# Wordpress meta query failing

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

got this code below and it's not returning any posts

I got a custom field named advertentiecategorie, with value 2 in multiple posts

```
<?php 
$blog_category = get_queried_object();

$args = array('post_type' => array( 'post' ),
'order'             =>  'DESC',
'orderby'           =>  'post_date',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
     array(

         array(
             'key'       => 'advertentiecategorie',
             'value'     => 2,
             'compare'   => '=',
         )
    )
)
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<ul>
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_field('event_thumbnail'); ?>" />
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            [<?php print_r(get_field('advertentiecategorie')[0]); ?>]
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

When trying without meta query code it workd, it works if I remove:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
     array(

         array(
             'key'       => 'advertentiecategorie',
             'value'     => 2,
             'compare'   => '=',
         )
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using one extra array for meta value

Please use the code below

```
$args = array('post_type' => array( 'post' ),
'order'             =>  'DESC',
'orderby'           =>  'post_date',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
         'meta_key'       => 'advertentiecategorie',
         'meta_value'     => 2,
         'meta_compare'   => '=',
     )
)
);
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, now it returns all posts

I looked in postmeta table and the value stored is not '2', but as an array:
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}
Extra field is set up with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @quokka please change the settings for that field in ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). save this field as single value not array or object..